# CollectionGroup Firestore cost in term of reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Currently my database structure is like this:
Collection posts where inside there is a subcollection users and inside users subcollection there i a subcollection called likes

if i run a query like this :

db.collectionGroup("likes").where("liked", "==", true);

and inside likes subcollection i have like 10k documents where field liked:true, the cost of this query in terms of read inside database is 10k (reads) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your query matches and returns 10K documents, you will be charged for 10K reads.  If this is a common action by your users, you may want to re-think your structure.

Comment: thank you, actually if i store all the likes inside an array in one single document, maybe i can break the 1MB limit, so currently i'm having some trouble to figure out which is the best strategy

Comment: Downloading 10K records just to see the count EACH TIME is pretty wasteful.  A more common technique is to have the aggregate count in a parent or other document, updated with the child documents are created.  That way you get the count with one read.  Precision, race conditions, etc are all possible issues - it depends on how precise you need the count (think about it - does it REALLY matter to a user if there are 11,432 or 11,433 likes?)

Comment: thank you for your moments and suggestions, actually i can make a cloud functions which is triggered when a user likes the post and update a counter inside a child document in that way i can only retreive this single document, probably more intelligent way as you suggest